Can't Verify CSRF Token Authenticity Error After Upgrading to Rails 7
I recently upgraded my Rails application from version 6 to version 7. In my form, I allow users to upload images, which was working correctly before the upgrade. However, after the upgrade, when I try to upload a second image after returning to the form, I encounter the following error:
"Can't verify CSRF token authenticity."
I have tried to bypass this error using the skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token option, but I understand that this practice may pose security issues.
How can I resolve this issue without compromising the security of my application?
I appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to address this problem safely and effectively.

How are returning to the form? Reloading the form should set the CSRF properly, so are you doing some partial load or something else?
